# what does '~' mean/do in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

While browsing some code online I've come across the following:

```
~Disposable()
{
   Dispose(false);
}
```

This doesn't produce any compiler errors, is the '~' doing anything in particular or why is it there?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Comment: it is destructor. syntactically same as c++

Comment: @ManishMishra It's not a destructor, and they make sure to not call it a destructor because it's very, *very* different from C++.

Comment: It's a _finalizer_ in C#, not a desctructor as in C++.

Comment: @280Z28: Unfortunatelly, they are called destructors. See the link posted by jure.

Comment: Sorry if it was a duplicate, but I swear google wasn't returning anything when searching for it.

Comment: @SOfanatic: Its hard to search for '~' ;-)

Comment: @SOfanatic We believe you ... once :-)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It's a mistake on MSDN. ECMA-334 §17.12 Includes the following note at the top: "Note: In the previous version of this standard, what is now referred to as a "finalizer" was called a
"destructor". Experience has shown that the term "destructor" caused confusion and often resulted to incorrect expectations, especially to programmers knowing C++..."

Comment: @280Z28: Ah, that's nice. Someone should file a bug report for the MSDN.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is called a [finalizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s71x931.aspx) in C#. What it does is override the `Finalize` method using a syntax similar to a destructor.